# Angular - Render Markdown with \n

Tags: html, angular, markdown

I'm trying to render Markdown inside an Angular application.

I was using [ngx-markdown](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown) with Angular 5 and it was working fine.

However, I had to upgrade to Angular 8 and since then, the `\n` are not rendered anymore. I read that with Angular 6, white spaces are not preserved anymore and that could be the issue.

[ngx-markdown](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown) proposes a fix by adding the directive `ngPreserveWhitespaces` but it still doesn't work.

I've tried another library, [ngx-md](https://github.com/dimpu/ngx-md), but it also fails to render `\n`

With [ngx-markdown](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown):

```
<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces >
    # Title \n ## Subtitle
</markdown>
```

With [ngx-md](https://github.com/dimpu/ngx-md):

```
<ngx-md>
  # Title \n ## Subtitle
</ngx-md>
```

They both render this:

[image]

I've also tried to do a .split('\n') and render the result using *ngFor, but the result is not perfect. Some block of text needs to be rendered at once, like code block.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Andrei Tătar, I made little progress.

Rendering the markdown like this works:

```
<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces >
    # Title &#x0a; ## Subtitle
</markdown>
```

But not like this:

```
const content = "# Title &#x0a; ## Subtitle"

<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces [data]="content" >        
</markdown>
```

And that is sadly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` means a new line in javascript. Html has a different syntax. You can add this character in html using `&#x0A;`.

**Note: you still need to use:** `ngPreserveWhitespaces`

```
<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces >
# Title  &#x0a; ## Subtitle
</markdown>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-markdown-ps7x5j?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you, it indeeds works when you hardcode the content. I have updated my question with more informations. I accepted your answer because it provide a solution for the initial problem

Comment: @Robouste in the js code it works with '\n'. Make sure the strings have '\n' and not '\\n' :) Maybe read about escaping special chars in javascript.

Comment: I get the content from a backend call wich returns something like : `# Title\n## Subtitle`

Comment: It might be that \n is not a special char but actually a backslash and an n. Try this in your javascript: `property = backendValue.replace('\\n', '\n');` If this works, something changed in your backend.