# ngx-markdown line break on every new line

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-markdown in my Angular app for writing posts.

Currently, I need two line breaks to achieve one line break in the result (the same behavior as in Stack Overflow). Is it possible to get the same behavior like (for example) the GitHub markdown?

I hoped to achieve this with `ngPreserveWhitespaces` but it doesn't worked:

```html
<textarea [formControl]="getFormContentControl('body')"></textarea>
<markdown [data]="getFormContentControl('body').value" ngPreserveWhitespaces></markdown>
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-markdown-ngx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please add a complete and reproducible example, f.e. a StackBlitz to get you helped. Read also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a stackblitz example

Comment: Thanks. I see [Angular - Render Markdown with \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285768/angular-render-markdown-with-n) is a similar question, but with no answer.

Comment: @Roy I found a solution and answered the question. Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2):

i know iam a little late, but i stumbled across the problem too and found a solution. You can configure ngxMarkdown to keep line breaks like GitHub does (the setting is even named that way).

Add the following Configurations to your app.module.ts (or whichever module you use to import ngxMarkdown):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MarkdownModule.forRoot({
      markedOptions: {
        provide: MarkedOptions,
        useValue: {
          gfm: true,
          breaks: true
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}]
```

ngxMarkdown uses marked for transforming the markdown content to html. You can use the "markedOptions" to edit the settings of marked. gfm enables GitHub flavored markdown and breaks enables linebreaks. You need to enable gfm to use line breaks.

Other available configuration options are listed here: https://marked.js.org/using_advanced#options

The configuration for ngx-markdown is also explained here: https://jfcere.github.io/ngx-markdown/get-started#configuration

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. On passing the value, I replace all line breaks (\n) with an HTML line break element:

html:

```
<textarea [formControl]="getFormContentControl('body')"></textarea>
<markdown [data]="lineBreak(getFormContentControl('body').value)" ngPreserveWhitespaces></markdown>
```

ts:

```
lineBreak(str): string {
  return str.replace(/\n/g, '</br>');
}
```